# c# interface inheritance - not recognizing base interface methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating an ASP layered web application and I have the following structure:

`IService<T>`

```
public interface IService<T> {

    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    void Add(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
```

`Service<T>`

```
    public class Service<T> where T : class {

        private IRepository<T> _repository;

        public Service(IRepository<T> repo) {
            this._repository = repo;
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> GetAll() {
            return _repository.GetAll();
        }

etc
```

And then I also have some 'custom services':

ICategoryService

```
  public interface ICategoryService : IService<Category> {

       IEnumerable<Category> GetProductCategories(int productId);

    }
```

CategoryService

```
public class CategoryService : Service<Category>, ICategoryService {

        private IRepository<Category> _repository;

        public CategoryService(IRepository<Category> repo) : base(repo) {
            this._repository = repo;
        }

         public IEnumerable<Category> GetProductCategories(int productId) {
            // implementation
        }
```

Controller:

```
 public class ProductController : Controller {
        private ICategoryService _cservice;

        public ProductController(ICategoryService cservice) {
            this._cservice = cservice;
        }
        ´ 
      // other methods

      public ActionResult Categories() {
                IEnumerable<Category> categories = _cservice.GetAll(); // doesn't work
        }
```

I'm trying to access the .GetAll() method in my controller, which was defined in IService and implemented in Service, but I'm getting a 'ICategoryService contains no definition for GetAll' error and I have no idea why.

I can access the .GetAll() method from my CategoryService, so I don't know why I can't access it from a CategoryService instance (via dependency injection).

Comment: Can you show full your controller code (with props and constructor)? This code looks good.

Comment: All I can think of is you have ICategoryService or IService defined twice and it takes the wrong interface

Comment: Updated the post with the controller's code

Comment: That says you don't have `GetAll` method in the interface `ICategoryService`. Not `doesn't work`.

Comment: Service<T> doesn't implement IService<T> - is this by design?

Comment: This c# code is valid, must be  either typo somehwere or a wrong class/interface is used (from a library or other project). Maybe one project is not build or wrong DLL reference.

Comment: @john No, it wasn't - it was a mistake. It's all working now, thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might have made a typo when posting your code, but, it seems that `Service<T>` doesn't implement `IService<T>` change the class's implementation to:

```
public class Service<T> : IService<T>
    where T : class 
{

    private IRepository<T> _repository;

    public Service(IRepository<T> repo) {
        this._repository = repo;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll() {
        return _repository.GetAll();
    }
```

I would also move the `where T : class` constraint from the class to interface.

Comment: Nevermind, this worked! :) Thank you! *kicks self for not noticing such a silly mistake*